# How to restart a 'stopped' bcache device?

Tags: bcache

I need to upgrade some drive firmware and I'd like to shut down bcache for the duration.

[The docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bcache.txt) show how to stop a bcache device:

> stop
>
> Write to this file to shut down the bcache device and close the backing device.

For me that will look like this:

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/stop
```

and for the cache device:

```
echo 1 > /sys/fs/bcache/<set-uuid>/stop
```

But how do I bring the device back (without rebooting the server)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply re-register each bcache device in the cache set (both backing and cache devices) to the kernel:

```
echo /dev/<path_to_device> > /sys/fs/bcache/register
```

Or, if the udev rules from bcache-tools are in place, then `partprobe` will automatically register the devices when they are scanned.